# UK residence for a mother of a baby who is UK citizen

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, citizenship, family

I am married to a British person and we are living outside the UK. My child is a UK citizen, do I need a visa to enter the UK?

Comment: Depends on your citizenship and for what purpose you intend to enter the UK. It might even depend on where you've been living and what permissions you have (if any needed) to live there as well.

Answer (score 4):

It depends. If you are a national of an EU country, or a country that has [a visitor agreement with the UK](https://www.visa-point.com/page/Travel_without_visa/), you can ENTER the UK without a visa. 
If you are a citizen of a country that is not on this list, you will need to apply [for a family visa](https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa) prior to arrival. If your country shares a visitor agreement with the UK, you can apply for a family visa once you are in the UK. You will need a family visa if you would like to stay with your child and spouse longer than 6 months.

Comment: But if she lives in the EU and has a "family member of an EU citizen" residence card derived from her husband and travels with her husband, she doesn't need a visa regardless of her nationality.

Comment: ^ True, that's the Surinder Singh's route.